# Use of like instead of that

Tags: meaning

> 1)There is no rule in the life that everyone must be rich.
>
> 2)There is no rule in the life like everyone must be rich.
>
> 3) It means that he will never participate in the elections .
>
> 4)It means like he will participate in the elections .

That is used in first sentences which I found on the internet . If I use ''like'' instead of that in these sentences would it be grammatically correct. I mean can ''like '' be used in this way? I think it means  ; there is such an idea but I am not sure if it is in this way or not .I thought if we can use it like '' say something like '' then we can use as is the case with sentences above . I think when we use “like” we are talk about unclear situation.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't use *like* in that way in correct English. If you mean 'something like this' you could say

"There is no **rule in life** *such as* 'Everyone must be rich'".

"It means *something like*…"

Comment: what is the difference between like and such as ?

Comment: In some contexts they can mean the same, but, as Keith says, _like_ is overused in some people's colloquial speech and your second sentence looks like slang.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use "like" in these sentences. It is a bad slang word that is used far too often and is not grammatically correct.